# Meteor - Template from multiple collections

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have two mongo collections:

- Posts: `{_id: "123", text: "some text", authorid: "456"}`
- Authors: `{_id: "456", name: "Cosmo"}`

And I would like to display the following template:

```
<template name="Postslist">
  {{#each posts}}
    {{>Post}}
  {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="Post">
  {{text}}
  {{name}}
</template>
```

So I have created a Post helper to display the associated name:

```
Template.Post.helpers({
  name: function() {
    var author = Authors.find({_id: this.authorid});
    return author.name;
  }
});
```

Unfortunately it does not display the author name like I would think. What am I doing wrong and how am I supposed to solve this kind of situation?

I know I'm not supposed to use foreign keys in NoSQL databases, but the collections are automatically populated by a 3rd party application and I cannot modify them.

Comment: [This article](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/reactive-joins-in-meteor/) might be of help. BTW, are you publishing/subscribing to both Posts and Authors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Find](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find) returns a mongo cursor not the matched documents. To get the matched documents from a cursor you have to use [fetch](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/fetch) however fetch is not reactive.

So to fix your problem and staying reactive you should return the result of [findOne](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/findone).

```
Template.Post.helpers({
    getAuthor: function() {
       return Authors.findOne({_id: this.authorid});
    }
});
```

Template changes:

```
<template name="Post">
    {{text}}
    {{#with getAuthor}}
        {{name}}
    {{/with}}
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that what the solution! Brilliant and very elegant too.